# Query Nested Mongodb info with Variable Nested Field names

Tags: json, mongodb

I have a MongoDB that is structured as below:

```
[
    {
        "subject_id": "1",
        "name": "Maria",
        "dob": "1/1/00",
        "gender": "F",
        "visits": {
            "1/1/18": {
                "date_entered": "1/2/18",
                "entered_by": "Sally"
            },
            "1/2/18": {
                "date_entered": "1/2/18",
                "entered_by": "Tim",
            }
        },
        "samples": {
            "XXX123": {
                "collected_by": "Sally",
                "collection_date": "1/3/18"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "subject_id": "2",
        "name": "Bob",
        "dob": "1/2/00",
        "gender": "M",
        "visits": {
            "1/3/18": {
                "date_entered": "1/4/18",
                "entered_by": "Tim"
            }
        },
        "samples": {
            "YYY456": {
                "collected_by": "Sally",
                "collection_date": "1/5/18"
            },
            "ZZZ789": {
                "collected_by": "Tim",
                "collection_date": "1/6/18"
            },
            "AAA123": {
                "collected_by": "Sally",
                "collection_date": "1/7/18"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

If I wanted to query the database to find all samples collected by Sally or all visits entered by Tim, what would be the best way of doing that?

I'm new to MongoDB and my attempts with various regex's haven't produced results. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I first used `project` on the required fields to use `objectToArray` followed by `unwind` to create separate records for array created in `project`.

The results are then filtered using `match`.

This works for the data provided in the question -

```
db.so.aggregate([
    {$project: {visits: {$objectToArray: "$visits"}, samples: {$objectToArray: "$samples"}}},
    {$unwind: "$visits"},
    {$unwind: "$samples"},
    { $match: { 
            $or : [
                { "visits.v.entered_by" : "Tim" },
                { "samples.v.collected_by" : "Sally" }
            ]
        }
    }
])
```